# Can you use an expression as a regex?

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

Can you use an expression as a case condition? Take, for example, the following code:

```
<switch description="Path based on the output" source="$body/output">
    <case regex="A|B">
        <call description="Send request to endpoint">
            <endpoint key="endpoint"/>
        </call>
    </case>
    <default/>
</switch>
```

This works and will send the message to the endpoint if the $body/output evaluates to either A or B.

Is it possible to store the "A|B" somewhere else (for example in an local-entry called "output.xml"), and use an expression in the case regex instead? For example:

```
    <case regex="get-property('output')">
```

If that's not possible and the case regex *has* to evaluate to a String, is it possible to store the contents of the local-entry in the sequence to I call upon them in the case regex, or does the case regex have to be "A|B"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AKAIK you can only have a `Regex` string in the case. The code also confirms [this](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/config/xml/SwitchCase.java#L104) where it seems to store the regex string as a `java.util.regex.Pattern` and uses `java.util.regex.Matcher` to match it against the source. So simply you have to have `A|B` or any other valid regex for the matcher to work.